# TF254024 - Upgrade from TFS 2005 to TFS 2010 to TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, tfs-2005

2 days ago I did the following test upgrade from TFS 2005 to 2010 then to 2012 (I am not configuring Reporting or Sharepoint)

1. Backed up the 6 TFs 2005 databases
2. Restored them on the Sql 2008 server used by TFS 2010
3. Ran TFSconfig setup uninstall:ALL on the TFS 2010 application server (as I had a test site setup)
4. Opened the TFS 2010 admin window and did an upgrade
5. Detached my TFS2010 collection and did an import process to TFS2012

Yesterday, I wanted to try the process again to make sure that I had all the steps down.
So I did some initial cleanup

1. Deleted all the databases on the TFS 2010 Sql server
2. Detached the test collection on TFS 2012 and then delete the associated database

and then I restarted the steps but it gets stuck at step #4

1. Backed up the 6 TFs 2005 databases
2. Restored them on the Sql 2008 server used by TFS 2010
3. Ran TFSconfig setup uninstall:ALL on the TFS 2010 application server
4. Opened the TFS 2010 admin window and did an upgrade

The error I get on step #4 is
TF254024: No database for Team Foundation Serer that can be upgraded were found on the following instance... Verify that you specified the correct name of the server and the instance.

I've double checked the name of the server & instance.
Made sure that the account that is running the upgrade has full permissions.

I'm not sure what else to do.  My searching hasn't proved that fruitful.

Comment: Silly question: You're sure the database restores were successful and that the SQL server instance is up and running, right?

Comment: Sql management studio told me they were all restored succesfully and I can random select * statement on the tables so I think we can rule that out ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

When I was testing out the deploy the first time, we were trying to do a migration instead of an upgrade.  We had added 2 extended properties to the master table from the TFSIntegration database (based on another error).

I removed both those extended properties and I was able to start the upgrade.

edit 1- 
I tried the process again (restore database and try to do the upgrade).  The extented properties were back again.

so running this script fixed the process.

```
USE TfsIntegration;
GO
EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty 
@name = N'TFS_DATABASE_CATEGORIES';
GO

EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty 
@name = N'TFS_INSTANCE';
GO
```

Comment: Wow, that's obscure. Good info!